# Is there a way I can convert a list of string into a list of int in python/flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have this list of strings:

```
data = ["23444,2345,5332,2534,3229"]
```

Is there a way I can convert it to list of int, like this:

```
[23444,2345,5332,2534,3229]
```

Comment: Important: This is not a list of strings. This is a list with exactly one string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the first element Then split string at  `,` and map with integer datatype it returns a lazy iterator convert it into list

```py
data = list(map(int,data[0].split(",")))
```

Comment: sorry @XonVersion5 could you mention it more clearly

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem sir, just remove the [1:-1], and it will work

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension should do it:

```
data = ["23444,2345,5332,2534,3229"]
newdata = [int(v) for v in data[0].split(',')]
print(newdata)
```

...or with map...

newdata = list(map(int, data[0].split(',')))

**Output:**

```
[23444, 2345, 5332, 2534, 3229]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to hold your new values and simply loop through the values and convert each to int.

**For example**

```
strings = ["2","3","4","5","6"]
 ints = []

for i in strings:

    ints.append(int(i))
```